# Proposal to cleanup [mx]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, clean-up

I ran across this tag and was curious what it was.  But what I discovered is a tag in need of some tender love and care.

---

**Tag** [mx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mx) (x132) - *No summary*

```
Mathematica serialized package format.

Used for the distribution of Mathematica packages.

Stores arbitrary Mathematica expressions in a serialized format optimized for fast loading.
Binary file format.

MX files cannot be exchanged between different operating systems or versions of Mathematica.

Developed by Wolfram Research.
```

---

But looking at the questions in the tag, I soon found at least 2 uses.  I have not seen any uses described in the wiki.

1. [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) used in DNS for email (seems to be most common use)

   - Recommend **Retag** or **Merge** to [mx-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mx-record) (and **Remove** usage of [record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/record))
   - Update wiki for [mx-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mx-record)
2. The `mx` namespace for Flex in Actionscript

   - Recommend **Retag** with [actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript) and [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) if not already

Based on the evidence so far, I don't think we need to keep this tag. Does this sound like a good plan and have I caught everything?

Answer (score 1):

**Done.**

1. [MX records][1] used in DNS for email (seems to be most common use)

   - **Retagged** to [mx-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mx-record)
2. The `mx` namespace for Flex in Actionscript (MX Controls)

   - **Retagged** with new tag [flex-mx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-mx)
3. Other random mentions of MX were moved to appropriate tags.